# Margins figure and subfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, subfloats

I have these two subfigures in a figure environment. I am unable to keep them inside the margin of my document. Any help will be great.
Thanks

```
\begin{figure}[H]   
   
   \medskip
   
   \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\textwidth}
       \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle}, sink/.style = {draw, circle, fill=blue!20}] 
           \node[sink] (1) {$1$}; 
           \node[main] (2) [below left of=1] {$2$}; 
           \node[main] (3) [left of=2] {$3$}; 
           \node[main] (7) [right of=2] {$7$}; 
           \node[main] (9) [right of=7] {$9$}; 
           \node[main] (10) [below of=2] {$10$}; 
           \node[main] (11) [below right of=10] {$11$}; 
           \node[main] (15) [below left of=10] {$15$};     
           \node[main] (4) [below left of=3] {$4$};    
           \node[main] (5) [below right of=13] {$5$}; 
           \node[main] (6) [below left of=4] {$6$};    
           \node[main] (8) [below right of=11] {$8$};  
           \node[main] (12) [below right of=5] {$12$};     
           \node[main] (14) [right of=4] {$14$};
           \node[main] (13) [below of=7] {$13$};                                                                                                               
           \draw[<-] (1) -- (3); 
           \draw[<-] (13) -- (2);              
           \draw[<-] (1) -- (7);   
           \draw[<-] (1) -- (9);   
           \draw[<-] (7) -- (5);
           \draw[<-] (3) -- (14);
           \draw[<-] (14) -- (4);
           \draw[<-] (4) -- (6);
           \draw[<-] (14) -- (10);
           \draw[<-] (12) -- (8);
           \draw[<-] (10) -- (15);
           \draw[<-] (7) -- (13);      
           \draw[<-] (13) -- (11);
           \draw[<-] (5) -- (12);          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
       \end{tikzpicture}   
       \caption{1a}
   \end{subfigure}\hfill
   \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\textwidth}
       \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle}, sink/.style = {draw, circle, fill=blue!20}] 
           \node[sink] (1) {$1$}; 
           \node[main] (2) [below left of=1] {$2$}; 
           \node[main] (3) [left of=2] {$3$}; 
           \node[main] (7) [right of=2] {$7$}; 
           \node[main] (9) [right of=7] {$9$}; 
           \node[main] (10) [below of=2] {$10$}; 
           \node[main] (11) [below right of=10] {$11$}; 
           \node[main] (15) [below left of=10] {$15$};     
           \node[main] (4) [below left of=3] {$4$};    
           \node[main] (5) [below right of=13] {$5$}; 
           \node[main] (6) [below left of=4] {$6$};    
           \node[main] (8) [below right of=11] {$8$};  
           \node[main] (12) [below right of=5] {$12$};     
           \node[main] (14) [right of=4] {$14$};
           \node[main] (13) [below of=7] {$13$};                                                                                                               
           \draw[<-] (1) -- (3); 
           \draw[<-] (1) -- (9);   
           \draw[<-] (3) -- (14);
           \draw[<-] (14) -- (10);
           \draw[<-] (10) -- (15);                                                                                                                                                 
       \end{tikzpicture}   
       \caption{1b}    
   \end{subfigure}
   \caption{1    }
\end{figure}
```

Below is the result I am obtaining at the moment. [image]. I am not sure what is happening as I cannot find any whitespace. Both linewidth and textwidth give the same result.

Any help will be great.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a working MWE (Minimal Working Example). Moreover, your code has bugs; e.g. node 5 requires the definition of node 13 to be before it.
I believe if you add `\centering` after figure environment is should be fixed. Also replace `\hfill` with `%` after the end of the first subfigure.

Comment: Your tikz picture is larger than the available space as well. This is mandated by `node distance = 15mm`. That is why the pictures are push to the right and are not centered, add `\centering` to subfigures as well.

Comment: In addition, maybe you can rescale your `tikzpicture`s, using `scale=.5, every node/.style={scale=0.7}` just find the right parameters!

Comment: You can add `\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);` before the end of the tikzpicture to see how big it is, but that is only  part of the problem.  You might also try using \subfloat (also in subcaption package) instead of subfigure.

Comment: Thanks everyone I used a combination of your comments and it is fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

I try to reproduce your images. In this I use syntax of the `positioning` library and adopt vertical and horizontal distances between nodes/vertices so, that both images can fit in the text area.

All nodes/vertices have the same size. They are placed in image code in the order, that coordinates for relative positions are always already defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\tikzset{
    node distance = 7mm and 4mm,
    V/.style = {circle, draw, semithick, minimum size=2em,
                fill=#1,
                inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
  V/.default = none,
every edge/.append style = {draw, thick, {Triangle[scale=0.8]}-}
        }
        
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[nodes=V]
\node[V=blue!20] (1) {$1$};
\node (2)   [below left=of 1]   {2};
\node (3)   [left=of  2]        {3};
\node (7)   [right=of 2]        {7};
\node (9)   [right=of 7]        {9};
\node (14)  [below=of 3]        {14};
\node (4)   [left=of 14]        {4};
\node (10)  [right=of 14]       {10};
\node (6)   [below left=of 4]   {6};
\node (15)  [below left=of 10]  {15};
%
\node (13)  [below=of 7]        {13};
\node (11)  [below right=of 10] {11};
\node (5)   [right=of 11]       {5};
\node (8)   [below left=of 5]   {8};
\node (12)  [below right=of 5]  {12};
    \end{scope}
%connections
 \draw  (1)     edge (3) 
        (13)    edge (2)
        (1)     edge (7)
        (1)     edge (9)
        (7)     edge (5)
        (3)     edge (14)
        (14)    edge (4)
        (4)     edge (6)
        (14)    edge (10)
        (12)    edge (8)
        (10)    edge (15)
        (7)     edge (13)
        (13)    edge (11)
        (5)     edge (12);
 \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{1a}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[nodes=V]
\node[V=blue!20] (1) {$1$};
\node (2)   [below left=of 1]   {2};
\node (3)   [left=of  2]        {3};
\node (7)   [right=of 2]        {7};
\node (9)   [right=of 7]        {9};
\node (14)  [below=of 3]        {14};
\node (4)   [left=of 14]        {4};
\node (10)  [right=of 14]       {10};
\node (6)   [below left=of 4]   {6};
\node (15)  [below left=of 10]  {15};
%
\node (13)  [below=of 7]        {13};
\node (11)  [below right=of 10] {11};
\node (5)   [right=of 11]       {5};
\node (8)   [below left=of 5]   {8};
\node (12)  [below right=of 5]  {12};
    \end{scope}
%connections
 \draw  (1)     edge (3)
        (1)     edge (9)
        (3)     edge (14)
        (14)    edge (10)
        (10)    edge (15);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{1b}
   \end{subfigure}
\caption{Comparison different connections between vertices}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @LatexUser, I didn't write any comments to your question, just provide a working solution. So I don't understand your comment :-(. If my solution works for you, you my consider to accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer).